Panel programmatically changing Select item
I am using Panel Select as the following:
selection = pn.widgets.Select(name="My Selection", groups=
{'group 1':{'item1': {'data1':1, 'data2':2}, 'item2': {'data1':3, 'data2':4}},
'group 2':{'item3': {'data1':1, 'data2':2}}})

I'd like to programmatically change the selected value (i.e. from 'item1' to 'item3')
What would be the best way to do it?
In addition, I'd like attach this Select widget to URL param (so I'd be able to preselect the item via URL argument (i.e. http://localhost:5006/app?selection=item3)


You can use selection.value = ... to update its value. In the following, I use the callback of a button to trigger a change between the selection's values.
You can use the Sync Widget to change the URL as you change the selection. You can have the user land on http://localhost:5006/app?selection=item3 for example, to select the item3 as default.

import panel as pn


def update_selection_value(event):
    """
    Update the selection's value to rotate between the three items.
    """
    selection.value = ["item1", "item2", "item3"][event.cls.clicks % 3]


selection = pn.widgets.Select(
    name="My Selection",
    groups={
        "group 1": {
            "item1": {"data1": 1, "data2": 2},
            "item2": {"data1": 3, "data2": 4},
        },
        "group 2": {"item3": {"data1": 1, "data2": 2}},
    },
)
button = pn.widgets.Button(
    name="Click to change selection value", button_type="primary"
)
button.on_click(update_selection_value)


# Allow URL syncing between the selection and its selected value.
if pn.state.location:
    # The URL parameter is called `selection`. 
    # You can call it anything you want.
    pn.state.location.sync(selection, {"value": "selection"})

pn.Row(button, selection).servable()


Thanks! So I have 2 follow up questions:

When you assign to value, you are not referencing the "groups" anyhow - which means "items" must be unique?
Providing Select widget to pn.state.location.sync is not working for me. It accepts only param objects. My class is inherited from param.Parameterized


The items have to be unique indeed.

As for point 2, I can't say why till I see your code. Checking the function definition for sync, we have def sync(self, parameterized: param.Parameterized, parameters: Optional[list[str] | dict[str, str]] = None, on_error: Optional[Callable[[dict[str, Any]], None]] = None) -> None:, which does accept param.Parameterized.
